# If $f:S^1 \to S^1$ is continuous and deg$(f)=\pm 1$, then $f$ is a homotopy equivalence.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $f:S^1 \to S^1$ be a continuous function such that its degree is deg$(f)=\pm 1$. Using [Whitehead theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_theorem#Statement.), I need to prove that $f$ is a homotopy equivalence.

My Attempt:

What I tried to do is to use the corollary mentioned in Wikipedia, which is obtained by combining Whitehead theorem with Hurewicz theorem, and has the following statement: "a continuous map $f : X \to Y$ between simply connected CW complexes that induces an isomorphism on all integral homology groups is a homotopy equivalence."

Since deg$(f)=\pm 1$, the function $f_*:\widetilde{H}_n(S^1) \to \widetilde{H}_n(S^1)$ is multiplication by $\pm 1$, so that $f$ is the identity or the antipodal map. In both cases, $f$ would be an homeomorphism, and then $f_*$ would be an isomoprhism for all $n$, and by the corollary mentioned above, $f$ is a homotopy equivalence.

I would like to know if my proof is correct or how can I prove this correctly. Can this be proved directly from Withehead theorem?

Diagram added:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
H_n(S^n) @>{f_*}>> H_n(S^n) \\
@VVV{h_*} @VVV{h_*}\\
\pi_n(S^n) @>{f_*}>> \pi_n(S^n)
\end{CD}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circle $S^1$ is not simply connected, so you cannot use the corollary. Instead you need to use Whitehead's Theorem which states that a continuous map between CW complexes is a homotopy equivalence if and only if it induces isomorphisms on all homotopy groups.

As $S^1$ is a CW complex and $\pi_n(S^1) = 0$ for $n \geq 2$, we see by Whitehead's theorem that $f : S^1 \to S^1$ is a homotopy equivalence if and only if the induced map $f_* : \pi_1(S^1) \to \pi_1(S^1)$ is an isomorphism.

Note that $\pi_1(S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ and the map $f_*$ is nothing but multiplication by $\deg f$. So $f_*$ is an isomorphism, and hence $f$ is a homotopy equivalence, if and only if $\deg f = \pm 1$.

Comment: But can we use $f_*:\pi_1(S^1) \to \pi_1(S^1)$ instaed of $f_*:\widetilde{H}_1(S^1) \to \widetilde{H}_1(S^1)$ to define deg$(f)$?

Comment: I'll note that nothing more than the calculation of the generators of the fundamental group of the circle is actually needed. Of course Whitehead works, but it is very much overkill.

Comment: @ConnorMalin: Of course, but it seems the OP needed to use Whitehead for some reason. I should have mentioned this was unnecessary.

Comment: @Twink: In this case, yes, because $S^1$ is one-dimensional and $\pi_1(S^1) \cong \tilde{H}_1(S^1)$. In general, the map $f_* : \pi_n(S^n) \to \pi_n(S^n)$ and the map $f_* : \tilde{H}_n(S^n) \to \tilde{H}_n(S^n)$ are both multiplication by $\deg f$. I'd also advise you to take note of Connor Malin's comment above (in particular, you don't need to use Whitehead in order to deduce that $f$ is a homotopy equivalence if $\deg f = \pm 1$).

Comment: The general case holds because $\pi_n(S^n) \cong \Bbb Z \cong \widetilde{H}_n(S^n)$? I saw a proof that $t \mapsto e^{2\pi i t}$ is a generator of $\widetilde{H}_1(S^1)=\pi_1(S^1)$, but it's a long proof. It looks easier to use Whitehead theorem than doing what Connor Malin said.

Comment: Yes, but you also need to know that the map $\pi_n(S^n) \to \tilde{H}_n(S^n)$ is an isomorphism. This is immediate follows from the Hurewicz Theorem.

Comment: And for $n=1$ we don't need to prove that?

Comment: Why $S^1$ being one-dimensional makes it different?

Comment: We do, but this also follows from Hurewicz. The reason I mention one-dimensional here is that the degree is detected in the top dimension, which is one in this case.

Comment: So, we need Hurewicz theorem to use $f_*:\pi_1(S^1) \to \pi_1(S^1)$ instaed of $f_*:\widetilde{H}_1(S^1) \to \widetilde{H}_1(S^1)$ to define deg$(f)$? I'm getting more confused.

Comment: If $M$ and $N$ are closed oriented $n$-dimensional manifolds, then $\tilde{H}_n(M) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ and $\tilde{H}_n(N) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ so $f_* : \tilde{H}_n(M) \to \tilde{H}_n(N)$ is nothing but multiplication by an integer; this is what we call the degree of $f$, denoted $\deg f$. In the special case of $M = N = S^n$, we can also detect the degree using $\pi_n$. In particular, $\pi_n(S^n) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, so $f_* : \pi_n(S^n) \to \pi_n(S^n)$ is nothing but multiplication by an integer; it turns out, this integer is precisely $\deg f$.

Comment: Ok this last comment is very clear to me, but in what moment did you need Hurewicz theorem?

Comment: You need Hurewicz to prove that the integer arising from the map $f_* : \pi_n(S^n) \to \pi_n(S^n)$ is the degree of $f$.

Comment: I'm trying to write the proof. Wikipedia says that "The Hurewicz theorem states that if $X$ is $(n − 1)$-connected, the Hurewicz map $h_* :\pi_k(X) \to H_k(X)$ is an isomorphism for all $k \leq n$ when $n \geq 2$ and abelianization for $n = 1$." But $\pi_1(S^1) \cong \Bbb Z$ is abelian, so $\pi_n(S^n) \cong H_n(S^n)$ for all $n \geq 1$, am I right?

Comment: I added a diagram to my question, do we get the lower $f_*$ as $f_*=h_* \circ f_* \circ h^{-1}_*$? And now I have to prove this composition is multiplication by $\deg{f}$?

Comment: That's correct.